# How to render image from JSON string into my react application?

Tags: json, reactjs

This is my JSON string:

```
{"blocks": 
[{
   "key":"mm3r",
   "text":"",
   "type":"unstyled",
   "depth":0,
   "inlineStyleRanges":[],
   "entityRanges":[],
   "data":{}}],
   "entityMap":
    {
      "0":
       {
         "type":"IMAGE",
         "mutability":"MUTABLE",
         "data":{"src":"https://t00.deviantart.net/1vvQLZ9mzHkH16x62-aLZmIlY1I=/fit-in/300x900/filters:no_upscale():origin()/pre00/e334/th/pre/f/2014/270/7/e/protect__luffy_x_suicidal_reader__by_wulferious-d80s516.png",
         "height":"auto",
         "width":"auto"
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Following is my react component:

```
let theObject;

class Blog extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.blogContent = props.blogContent;
    this.blogId = props.blogId;



}
```

This is where I'm doing JSON.parse

```
componentWillMount(){
    theObject = JSON.parse( this.blogContent );
    console.log(this.blogContent);
}
```

Here is my render part. Presently I'm just calling theObject.blocks[i].text which works fine but I don't know how to render the image. In short how should I call it??

```
render(props) {
    return(
        <div className = "blog header">
        {
            Array.from(Array(theObject.blocks.length), (e, i) => {
                return <p key={i}>{theObject.blocks[i].text }</p>
            })}

        </div>
          );
        }
}

Blog.proptypes = {
    blogContent: Proptypes.string
}

export default Blog;
```

Comment: seems like you would need to iterate over the `entityMap` keys and use the `data.src` for each of them `<img  src={data.src} />`

Comment: Thanks,  got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you would need to iterate over the `entityMap` [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and use the `data.src` for each of them for the image source.
Something along these lines:

```
Object.values(theObject.blocks[i].entityMap).map(val => <img src={val.data.src} />)
```